# Wordpress Pages With Categories and category url in page link

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I have created a taxonomy (category) for pages (not for posts).

```
add_action('init', function() {
     
register_taxonomy('arrest_records', ['page'], [
    'label' => __('Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'arrest-records', 'hierarchical' => true ),
    'with_front' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'labels' => [
        'singular_name' => __('Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'all_items' => __('All Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'view_item' => __('View Page Categories', 'txtdomain'),
        'update_item' => __('Update Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'new_item_name' => __('New Arrest Records Name', 'txtdomain'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'parent_item' => __('Parent Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Arrest Records', 'txtdomain'),
        'not_found' => __('No Arrest Records found', 'txtdomain'),
    ]
]);
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('arrest_records', 'page');
```

How can I have category name and eventually subcategory name in page link?

For example:

now I have:
https://www.example.com/john-doe

and I would like to have:

https://www.example.com/category/sub-category/john-doe

Of course John Doe it is assigned to Category / sub-category.

Thank you very much.

I tried this:

```
$rules = array();
$tax = 'arrest_records';
$post_type = 'page';

$terms = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => $tax,
'hide_empty' => false,
) );
            
// var_dump($terms->slug);
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^page/(' . $term->slug . ')[/]?$', 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type . '&' . $tax . '=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
```

I did not succeed anything, I mean the link for pages that are assigned to category are not changes.

Note: Changing permalinks is not helping me since that setting only affects posts, not pages.